# char array displaying garbage after instantiation using new

Tags: c++, arrays

I am try to concatenate the following 4 things to an char array(in C++) so i can return my array but along with those 4 things i am also getting garbage in my array. can anyone kindly help

```
char* Guest::toString()
{

    char * p = new char[30];

    p[0] = firstName[0];
    p[1] = '.';
    p[2]=lastName[0];
    p[3] = '.';
        return p;
}
```

Comment: Scope of p will be removed when you return the local array

Comment: try adding `p[4] = 0;`

Comment: It is hard to tell from the code. Add extra info. Where are firstName and lastName? Also, you need to pad the null-terminated character. Moreover, you can't return C-style array in C++.

Comment: adding '\0' at p[4] worked

Answer (score 2):

The elements of an array are uninitialized upon creation, so in your case everything past p[3] is still uninitialized. Attempting to access these uninitialized elements will result in undefined behavior, which is why you're getting garbage data.

I believe that you can initialize it by using:

```
char * p = new char[30]();
```